# Mirrors/optics and physical adaptation of the eye

Tags: optics

Is it possible to use a clever combination of lenses and mirrors placed between your eye and a screen 1m away from you to make the eye react to the screen as if it were 20m away from you?

Note that I'm not asking whether it's possible to make the light rays travel a total distance of 20m, but whether the eyes will react as if the screen were 20m away.

(Not sure if this is the right StackExchange for this. If it isn't, please let me know where else I should post this, thanks!)

Comment: Do you eyes know how far away the things you look at are? Assuming 20/20 vision.

Comment: Do you mean for example by using a convex lens, generating an image with $v<0$?

Answer (score 0):

You mean aside from using lots of mirrors so that the light actually travels 20 m before it hits your eye?

Yes you can do this, from a lens point of view you just want to change the divergence of the rays from a single point. If it is 1 m away they will be more divergent and require more power to focus by your eye. If it's further away they will be less divergent. From an image size point of view, think of looking through a set of binoculars the wrong way around.